# How to monitor set operation on a pure property?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, properties

I have a property:

```
public Foo My Foo{ get; set; }
```

I want to **monitor** set operation on it but **break-point** not settled on it, How to monitor it without changing code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(visual studio menu) Debug -> New Breakpoint -> Break at function...

getter: `ClassName.get_PropertyName()` 
in your example, this would be `Class.get_MyFoo()`

setter: `ClassName.set_PropertyName(PropertyType)`
in your example, this would be `Class.set_MyFoo(Foo)`

Comment: What Line and Character textbox must be fill in dialog form of Break at function?

Comment: Thanks, that's exact my requirement.

Comment: @RedHat You can leave other fields as they are

Answer (score 1):

You can't, as far as I'm aware. If you want the property to do anything non-trivial, you need a full implementation of the property instead of an automatically-implemented one. It's not hard to do, of course - that automatically implemented property is just equivalent to:

```
private Foo myFoo;

public Foo MyFoo
{
    get { return myFoo; }
    set { myFoo = value; }
}
```

So just convert it to that form and add whatever code you need (logging etc).

Comment: Ok, that's true, but i not have permission to change code, I think maybe exist a way without change code but apparently i have no choice.

Comment: @RedHat: What sort of "monitoring" are you talking about, and how much code can't you change?

Comment: @Jon Skeet:This property is in model and i haven't permission to change model,But i want to know which code set myFoo property unexpectedness in my code or binding or something else.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot modify the existing code and still want to be able to intercept calls to existing methods you may checkout [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/) or maybe the [profiler API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300553.aspx).